# Replace the Obscuring Character in a TextField widget with an Icon

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield, flutter-dependencies

So I'd like to have a TextField Widget in my project that uses a Material Icon as the obscuring character instead of a String.

If anyone has any tips on how to do this or can point me in the right direction towards a guide, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/pin_input_text_field this is the package you are looking for. Read the documentation and lets go :) You can check the pub.dev for this kind of features that are not in the flutter.

Comment: Surely there's a way to repurpose the TextField widget though to support Icons instead of the String?

Comment: Unfortunately I've come across the package before and it doesn't fit my use case :( I appreciate the help though